# How to get JsonArray from a class who AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I'm trying to create a class to retrieve a JsonArray from a url. 
This class extends AsyncTask to avoid creating multiple AsyncTasks on interfaces.

The class works fine on debugger, but I do not know what to do to get the return object. Can anyone help me?

Here's my class:

```
public class QueryJsonArray extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

JSONArray jsonRetorno = null;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";

    try {           

        Log.i(getClass().getName(), params[0]);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet( params[0]);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }else{

            is = null;
        }


    } catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    if(is!=null){
        try {           
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();             
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            jsonRetorno = new JSONArray(result);            
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
    return null;
      }
         }
```

And I want to retrieve like this:

```
QueryJsonArray obj = new QueryJsonArray();
JSONArray jArray = obj.execute(myUrl);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you get the string from response you can put it in JSONobject("your response as string ")

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. 
My question is not that. What I want to know is how can I get the JSONArray from another class after AsyncTask end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a *callback*. Simply add the following…

variable:

```
private Callback callback;
```

inner-interface:

```
public interface Callback{
    public void call(JSONArray array);
}
```

constructor:

```
public QueryJsonArray(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

Additionally, change your class declaration to:

```
public class QueryJsonArray extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>
```

and change the return type of `doInBackground` to `JSONArray`.

At the end of `doInBackground`, add:

```
return jsonRetorno;
```

Finally, add the following method with contents:

```
public void onPostExecute(JSONArray array) {
    callback.call(array);
}
```

---

Now, to execute the task, just do:

```
QueryJsonArray obj = new QueryJsonArray(new Callback() {
    public void call(JSONArray array) {
        //TODO: here you can handle the array
    }
});
JSONArray jArray = obj.execute(myUrl);
```

---

As a side note, you could greatly simplify all of this using a third party library, such as my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library, which would condense all of the above code to:

```
$.ajax(new AjaxOptions().url(myUrl).success(new Function() {
    public void invoke($ d, Object… args) {
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) args[0];
        //TODO handle the json array.
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Phil, 8 years ago you helped me with this explanation. I can't express how grateful I am to you, it took me a few months to understand how callbacks work, at this point they were pure magic to me. Thanks a lot man, you definitely made me continue in the developer career.